# why does net control hear a check-in which I do not hear?

Tags: uhf, procedure, audio

Sometimes on a net, net control acknowledges a check-in that I haven't heard. That is, I hear some check-ins but not others. Not poor signal, just silence. But net control hears it.
Why might that be?

[Me: new ham, Yaesu HT]

Comment: Is this net being run on a repeater?  Or is it being done via simplex?

Comment: It starts on a repeater, then switches to simplex.
Also I see I should have added my callsign: Eve KM6QKG
Thanks

Comment: So you heard everyone via the repeater, but the simplex portion, you couldn't hear all the other stations?  That's not unusual.  Simplex and HF nets often use relay stations to relay messages and checkins to the net control, so the net control isn't able to hear everyone either in some cases. :)

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations on your new license! Since you referenced an HT, it would seem you are talking about VHF or UHF nets.

VHF and UHF signals are generally line of sight communications. If your antenna is too low, a signal can be blocked by buildings, hills, etc. If the net control station (NCS) has better elevation or antenna height, the NCS will be able to hear more stations.

Another possibilty relates to gain/sensitivity. If the NCS has a higher gain antenna system or a more sensitive receiver, the NCS will be able to receive weaker signals.

So if you are using your flexible rubber antenna on your HT and the NCS is using a collinear antenna on a 50 foot tower, the NCS will generally hear more stations than you can. Work to improve the height and gain of your antenna system.

Of few other less likely possibilities are:

- Your squelch is set too high. Try opening the squelch to see if you can hear some of the stations that the NCS can hear.
- If you are using a repeater, make sure you have the correct transmit CTCSS tone programmed and don't initially use a receive tone.
- If on a repeater, make sure you are not operating upside down (transmit and receive frequencies transposed).

Comment: Thank you for this - Your first suggestion seems the most likely answer. (Possibly squelch too, I will try).
My radio has a bunch of repeaters loaded via Chirp & auto-sends the CTCSS. 
I'm feeling pleased that I at least understand the discussion - that's progress.
Thank you for your time.
Eve KM6QKG